# Regex Extra Line Error

Tags: php, regex, string, newline

I was having an issue when I input comments into a log table the display would be incorrect.

### For example when I input:

```
1                 
2            
3
```

### It would show up as:

```
1

2

3
```

### To deal with this problem I commented out some of the code and added this regex line:

```
//$notes= str_replace("</br>","<br>",$sqlresult['Notes']); 
//$notes = str_replace("\r","",$sqlresult['Notes']); 
//$notes = str_replace("\n","",$sqlresult['Notes']); 
//$notes = str_replace("\\","",$sqlresult['Notes']); 
//$notes = str_replace("\r","<P>",$sqlresult['Notes']); 
$notes = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s/', '<br>', $sqlresult['Notes']));
```

However now I am receiving an error when text is pasted from an application that appears as one line is coming up with a lot of extra lines in betweem.

E.g.

```
Files are.. CDSEYE SUBMIT BY M99-CDSENTD
```

### Display:

```
Files are...  
CDSXEYE     


(10 EXTRA BLANK LINES)



  SUBMIT BY M99-CDSENTD
```

Is there anyway I can get the $notes to display input EXACTLY how it is inputted?

Comment: Have you tried using `nl2br`?

Comment: @Karo no I have not, how would that look if it was added to my code?  I want to test it.

Comment: `$notes = nl2br($sqlresult['Notes'])` instead of your regex, but it depends on how they're stored in `$sqlresult['Notes']`

Comment: @Karo Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\htdocs\ConferenceCall\Menutable.php on line 1615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you had to use the

```
$notes = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s/', '<br>', $sqlresult['Notes']));
```

line in the first place is because there was something wrong with the way you were handling input and storing it in a sql database.  We merely plugged that hole by removing that extra newline at the end.  If we wanted a true 1 to 1 input to output, we would need to look at the way the data is stored from the input textbox to the sql database.  Also how it is being pulled from that database and displayed back to the output.  If somebody else wrote this code, then it may take a while to find how that was done.

**final answer ended up being:**

```
$notes = trim(preg_replace('/\r\r/', '<br>', $sqlresult['Notes']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your replacing every 2 spaces with a line break (`<br>`), this would be the reason for your breaks.

```
$notes = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s/', '<br>', $sqlresult['Notes']));
```

I suggest remove the above code and then put

```
 echo nl2br($your_text_variable); //in the view
```

Comment: this removed the entire content of the column

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the second to last line, where you're replacing **\r** with **<p>**, which adds an extra blank line. Try **<br>** instead.

Comment: I uncommented it and put <br> but now ive gone a step back and am receiving the same problem as before:

Comment: that line was commented out, it isn't affecting anything